# Não consigo importar as bibliotecas do SDL2 de forma correta

Tags: c, sdl

Sempre que tento compilar o seguinte projeto:

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
int main( int argc, char* args[] ) 
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0; 
}
```

com o seguinte comando no cmd:

```
gcc -o test.exe teste.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

eu recebo os seguintes erros:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKkHEnv.o:teste.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKkHEnv.o:teste.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Já pesquisei bastante mas não consegui achar uma solução, mesmo com as outras pessoas que tinham problemas similares. Peguem leve, sou novato nisso skksksksks.

Comment: Pela linha de comando, você está utilizando a versão da SDL2 instalada através do msys2 (e não a do site da lib SDL2). Verifique se é realmente esta, a versão que você pretende utilizar e se ela está atualizada, pois tanto o programa como o comando para compilar estão corretos. Um teste que pode ajudar, é tentar    acrescentar o parâmetro `-DSDL_MAIN_HANDLED` na linha de comando do gcc. Se funcionar, talvez o problema esteja na instalação/configuração do msys2 e/ou da lib SDL2.

Comment: use os parâmetros em `main()`. A assinatura de main deve ter os dois parâmetros.